# PayPal oauth2 authorization and .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, paypal

So I'm trying to set up PayPal sign-in within my .net core application. I'm using this 3rd party library to do so: https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers

I'm building my application upon Umbraco CMS, and within the appropriate section I use the following:

```
builder.AddMemberExternalLogins(logins =>
{
    logins.AddMemberLogin(
        memberAuthenticationBuilder =>
        {
            memberAuthenticationBuilder.AddPaypal(
                memberAuthenticationBuilder.SchemeForMembers(PayPalMemberExternalLoginProviderOptions.SchemeName),
                options =>
                {
                    options.ClientId = clientId;
                    options.ClientSecret = clientSecret;
                });
        });
});
```

Out of the box, this does not work. From reading around it seems that it seems the authorization endpoints are using the live values, and these are not appropriate for testing with Paypal's sandbox endpoints.

After reading the following thread: https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/issues/198 I can see that this user had to update the endpoints manually to use different values:

```
.AddPaypal(options =>
               {
                   options.ClientId = Startup.Configuration["Authentication:Paypal:ClientId"];
                   options.ClientSecret = Startup.Configuration["Authentication:Paypal:ClientSecret"];
                   options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/auth/protocol/openidconnect/v1/authorize";
                   options.TokenEndpoint = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/tokenservice";
                   options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/userinfo?schema=openid";
               })
```

Now once updating these values, the authorization *seems* to work. But I've found it to be very unreliable. On my personal dev machine it seems to allow me to authorize, but when testing with another colleague, he finds he is constantly logged out and sometimes it doesn't authorize at all.

When I look at the previous thread I can see that this was written in 2017, and I'm wondering if the endpoints have been updated or the process has been changed entirely by Paypal, but I can't find any documentation on this.

Basically I'm looking for the simplest way to integrate Paypal sign-in on my application. When I read Paypal's documentation (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/log-in-with-paypal/integrate/) I only see mention of refreshing the token, I don't see anything about an authorization endpoint or user information endpoint.

I'm getting quite confused and I'm wondering if anyone has successfully managed to set up a Paypal sign-in with a .net core application in 2022 and whether they have any sample code.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That does seem like an old integration. I would advise following https://developer.paypal.com/docs/log-in-with-paypal/integrate/ from scratch, which can be implemented in any language for the eventual server-side calls. The initial client-side authorization is done in either the JS popup or using a redirect (JS is better)

After exchanging the resulting authorization_code for a refresh token, that token can then be used to obtain information about the user's account (or do API operations involving it), according to the scopes that were authorized.